# How Can I Draw Using Stars To "W" Letter

Tags: c, ascii, draw

How can I draw a "W" pattern using only stars and with height input?
For example: height of stars input: 5 output picture:

[image]
Here is my code (it's working but input is broken and first star line are not including spaces):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k,l,m,step=1;;
    printf("height of stars:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        for(k=3;k>=i;k--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        for(l=1;l<=i;l++)
        {
            printf("  ");
        }
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        for(m=3;m>=i;m--)
        {
            printf("  ");
        }
        for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        step+=2;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not using the input variable `i` for anythng. Instead, you're using the same variable for the first `for` loop.

Comment: What is the `step` variable for?

Comment: You can't make that output pattern on a monospace terminal. Notice how the stars do not make vertical columns, but are offset, however there isn't room between the stars on the adjacent rows for a space.

Comment: Instead of an image show us the expected monospaced text output, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* stars = "***";
    char* spaces = "                 ";
    int height = 5;
    
    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%.*s%s%.*s%.*s%s%.*s",   i, spaces, stars, height-i-1, spaces, height-i-1, spaces, stars, i, spaces);
        printf("%.*s%s%.*s%.*s%s%.*s\n", i, spaces, stars, height-i-1, spaces, height-i-1, spaces, stars, i, spaces);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4400KB
***        ******        ***
 ***      ***  ***      *** 
  ***    ***    ***    ***  
   ***  ***      ***  ***   
    ******        ******
```

Comment: If you turn this in to your teacher, good luck trying to explain it!
If you submit work as your own, you *must* be prepared to explain it and defend it.